# Bootstrap change Breadcrumb divider with base 64 image code

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, breadcrumbs

I am trying to change the bootstrap breadcrumb divider symbol.I have referred few [online links](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/components/breadcrumb/) and tried the following. But it is not working. I hope I would have some help on making it work.

```
<nav aria-label="breadcrumb">
  <ol class="breadcrumb">
    <li class="breadcrumb-item"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li class="breadcrumb-item"><a href="#">Library</a></li>
    <li class="breadcrumb-item active">Data</li>
  </ol> 
</nav>
//CSS
    $breadcrumb-divider: url(data:image/svg+xml;base64,PHN2ZyB4bWxucz0iaHR0cDovL3d3dy53My5vcmcvMjAwMC9zdmciIHdpZHRoPSI4IiBoZWlnaHQ9IjgiPjxwYXRoIGQ9Ik0yLjUgMEwxIDEuNSAzLjUgNCAxIDYuNSAyLjUgOGw0LTQtNC00eiIgZmlsbD0iY3VycmVudENvbG9yIi8+PC9zdmc+) !important;
```

Please find the codepen eample [here](https://codepen.io/JGSpark/pen/KYeVVP?editors=1100)

Comment: You have to use preprocessing to overwrite variables. Read about LESS/SASS/other. If you are not able to use preprocessing you have to manualy override it.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to make it with CSS, you should write it like:

```
.breadcrumb-item+.breadcrumb-item::before {
    content: url(data:image/svg+xml;base64,PHN2ZyB4bWxucz0iaHR0cDovL3d3dy53My5vcmcvMjAwMC9zdmciIHdpZHRoPSI4IiBoZWlnaHQ9IjgiPjxwYXRoIGQ9Ik0yLjUgMEwxIDEuNSAzLjUgNCAxIDYuNSAyLjUgOGw0LTQtNC00eiIgZmlsbD0iY3VycmVudENvbG9yIi8+PC9zdmc+);
}
```

for SASS, you can use:

```
$breadcrumb-divider: url(data:image/svg+xml;base64,PHN2ZyB4bWxucz0iaHR0cDovL3d3dy53My5vcmcvMjAwMC9zdmciIHdpZHRoPSI4IiBoZWlnaHQ9IjgiPjxwYXRoIGQ9Ik0yLjUgMEwxIDEuNSAzLjUgNCAxIDYuNSAyLjUgOGw0LTQtNC00eiIgZmlsbD0iY3VycmVudENvbG9yIi8+PC9zdmc+);
```

but you need to declare it before you import bootstrap.